# Enable-Migrations command changed something

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Googling this issue, I've tried all the answers to my problem with no change.

I have a small MVC e-commerce app I am building for my company. It is divided into two projects: Domain and WebUI. WebUI is obviously dependent on Domain and my build-order reflects this. I've checked target frameworks for both projects and they match (4.5) and I have EF 5.0 added.

After building the basic product presentation/catalog and cart code I want to implement users so I can build the order/store functions.

Everything is working fine until this point.

I run "Enable-Migrations" so I can write my own membership/user code and use the DB I have setup so future context changes target my DB instead of the defaultOCnnection.

Enable Migrations inserted the Migrations folder and Configuration class. Ran with no errors produced. "Checking if the context targets and exisiting database ... Code First Migrations enabled for project *.WebUI."

When I attempted a Build after running Enable-Migrations, I received a number of errors stating that The type or namespace 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' in the Domain project (my product class) and one error 'Could not resolve reference. Could not locate assembly "System.Web.Mvc, Version 4.0.0.0 ...." Check to make sure the assembly exists on the disk ..." And of course an error from WebUI that it could not locate the Domain.dll (because Domain.dll fails to build).

How did running enable-Migrations cause this?

How do I resolve this? The dll is on the disk, right where the properties say it is, Reference included, Local Copy=true ....

I'm really at a loss to figure this one out ....

Comment: Is your context in your domain project? Which project did you target when enabling migrations?

Comment: Yes. Context is in .Domain with entities and repositories. I did not explicitly target either project.

Comment: After doing some more googling, it appears I probably ran the Enable-Migrations targeting the WebUI project. Which only makes me wonder why the Domain project was affected in this way?

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, I encountered this error two days ago on one of our machines, the only difference being that we are running EF 6.1.1. I used ReSharper to check that nothing in our domain project was using System.Web.Mvc and I removed the reference. I couldn't figure out how it got there anyway.

We ran enable-migrations maybe a couple of years ago on this code base, so it would seem unlikely that our issue was caused by that.

For your part, there really shouldn't be much of a reason to have a reference to System.Web.Mvc in your domain code, so perhaps you could look at moving whatever code is depending on that DLL into your web project, if it can't be outright deleted, then remove the DLL reference itself?

I know this doesn't explain why it doesn't just work. That might have something to do with assembly redirects in the app.config file, perhaps. Maybe it's redirecting to v5, which isn't there?

Comment: Domain has the entities. I was using Freeman's Sports Store book as a basis for this. My intention was to use it as a basic template and adding better functionality. One of the core entities is decorated with a HiddenInput attribute which requires System.Web.Mvc.

Comment: I know this still isn't directly solving your problem, but is it really right to be putting UI hints on your domain model? That concern should belong to the view, rather than the domain? I know it's being a little pedantic, but if that's the only reason you've got MVC referenced then it wouldn't seem a huge let down to have to use `@Html.HiddenFor` in your view for binding to that property.

Comment: Good point. One I can surely try to see if that at least clears the error and lets the solution compile. I just don't understand why the Enable command even touched the Domain code.

Comment: I still don't understand how running Enable-Migrations did this, but, I finally resolved the issue. I actually had a copy of the solution from several days ago before I ran Enable-Migrations. I opened that to just start my edits over again and actually got the same errors. I deleted the reference in Domain to System.Web.Mvc in an assembly folder, and added a reference to it from the local package folder and everything cleared. Just plain weird.